# $_.SubString($_.IndexOf("")) Powershell assistance

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to isolate the first **three** octets of an IPv4 address

```
$IPAddress = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration |
Where { $_.IPAddress } |
Select -Expand IPAddress |
where { $_ -like '*.*' } | % {
$_.SubString($_.IndexOf(""))
}

Write-host IP Address is $IPAddress
```

My output is currently

```
IP Address is 192.168.10.78
```

Could someone put me out of my misery and tell me what I need to do with the SubString / IndexOf in order to knock off everything after and including the final .  so it reads

```
IP Address is 192.168.10
```

I'm sorry, but I'm a complete newbie, and it's taken me 2 hours to write/steal these 6 lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is without using substring

```
( Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Where { $_.IPAddress } | 
Select -Expand IPAddress  ) | % { $_.split('.')[0..2] -join '.' }
```

this using substring:

```
( Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Where { $_.IPAddress } | 
Select -Expand IPAddress  ) | % {$_.substring(0, $_.LastIndexOf('.')) }
```